# Devrais-je réussir le DALF?

Tags: france, professions, travail

Dans quel cas devrais-je considérer le DALF C1 ou C2?

Pour aller étudier en France on me demande d'avoir réussi le DELF B2, même pour une maîtrise ou pour un doctorat. Alors, pourquoi devrais-je réussir le DALF?

Comment: Indeed, according to this https://leipzig.institutfrancais.de/cours-de-francais/delf-dalf/pourquoi-passer-le-delf-dalf you might need only the DELF B2. Else, it seems that for immigration: http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/immigrer-installer/etudiants/demeurer-quebec/demande-csq/etudiants-peq/exigences-linguistiques.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Le DALF C2** est le plus haut diplôme de français langue étrangère.
Au niveau C2, la maîtrise de la langue se traduit par un degré de précision, d'adéquation et d'aisance dans l'expression. Le candidat de C2 est capable de réaliser des tâches académiques ou de niveau avancé.

**Le DALF C1** peut être requis pour intégrer certaines grandes écoles françaises. De plus, il constitue un avantage pour les demandes de bourses, pour l'immigration au Canada et pour l'accès à certains emplois.

Answer (score 1):

Soit dit en passant, si vous souhaitez poursuivre des études en France, je vous propose vivement la série des ouvrages universitaires **Réussir ses études en français**

https://www.pug.fr/collection/80/Reussir%20ses%20etudes%20en%20francais

(Éditions PUG)

Comme l'on peut voir leur niveau ne se limite pas obligatoirement à B2. Prénons les études d'ingénieur. J'ai lu le livre concernant ce domaine après avoir obtenu le Delf B2 et je pourrais dire que j'avais pas mal de difficultés pour suivre aisément le contenu.

Dalf n'est pas obligatoire, certes. Or, vous bénéficierez de la lecture des livres qui appartiennent d'une part à ce niveau et d'autre part au domaine que vous étudierez.